# Minimum Version RH for Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, redhat

I have a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga) and I need to install **Python 3.6.x** or at least a **version 3.x**. 
I don't find any reference to the minimum version of RH that supports Python 3.x. ( I know for example that I can't install it on *RH 3*).

Python 3.x is supported on RH 5.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need at least RHEL 6 to add Python 3.x (via software collections). See the [lifecycle page](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/rhscl-rhel6).